# static function definition in header

Tags: c++, static

In a header `xxx.h`:

```
static int yyy();
int yyy()
{
    return 0;
}
```

If I include xxx.h into a cpp file, is yyy() still a static function?

Comment: What do you mean by a static function?

Comment: The syntax rules of C++ don't depend on whether instructions are in a header file or a source file. Headers are included into source files to make a "compilation unit", and that is compiled.

Comment: Given the above code the obvious question is why not an inline function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, still static. Every compilation unit (.cpp file) will have its own version of `yyy`.

Compiler does not "see" header files. They are gone in pre-processing stage, where each `#include` is replaced with the text of the file contents of that `#include`, and the compiler will see only one very long stream of characters.

Comment: I tried an simple validation. If I remove definition of yyy(), even the signature is different to its declaration, compiler still throws 'undefined function' error message to me. So it can be confirmed that compiler use the definition of yyy(). Am I right?

Comment: @naive231 I don't understand your problem. Please provide more details. But describe the problem in another StackOverflow question.